# Can't change DataContext WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to use a MVVM pattern instead of putting all logic in the code-behind file, but I can't seem to get it working.

My view is this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp4.ViewModel"       
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModelMain />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
namespace WpfApp4.ViewModel
{
    class ViewModelMain
    {
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: It gives me an error saying that ViewModelMain doesn't belong in the namespace WpfApp4.ViewModel (vm:ViewModelMain).

Comment: Try making the class `ViewModelMain` as `public` and build it.

Comment: It does run, but get a message that says it doesn't exist in the namespace when hovering over the line in the xaml file. Should I just ignore it?

Comment: The warning may have stuck there because I can't find any problem with the code. Try restarting the window/project/VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio can be a bit temperamental sometimes with xaml warnings and errors. Try closing the window, and/or cleaning and rebuilding the project, or if all else fails close all windows and restart visual studio

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It did indeed remove the warning, but event handlers still seem to show up in the code-behind file.

Comment: @Pelle, with MVVM you bind Commands, you don't use event handlers.

Comment: That's totally correct. Still a lot of practice left... Thanks for the help, you solved my problem! Really annoying, though, that I have to restart Visual Studio so often.